# SSH key for AWS Autoscaling Group node not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

So I created the autoscaling group using the following Terraform files:

Autoscaling group:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "orbix-mvp" {
  desired_capacity     = 1
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.orbix-mvp.id}"
  max_size             = 1
  min_size             = 1
  name                 = "${var.project}-${var.stage}"
  vpc_zone_identifier  = ["${aws_subnet.orbix-mvp.*.id}"]

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "${var.project}-${var.stage}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-${var.stage}"
    value               = "owned"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

Launch configuration:

```
# This data source is included for ease of sample architecture deployment
# and can be swapped out as necessary.
data "aws_region" "current" {}

# EKS currently documents this required userdata for EKS worker nodes to
# properly configure Kubernetes applications on the EC2 instance.
# We utilize a Terraform local here to simplify Base64 encoding this
# information into the AutoScaling Launch Configuration.
# More information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/launch-workers.html
locals {
  orbix-mvp-node-userdata = <<USERDATA
#!/bin/bash
set -o xtrace
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh --apiserver-endpoint '${aws_eks_cluster.orbix-mvp.endpoint}' --b64-cluster-ca '${aws_eks_cluster.orbix-mvp.certificate_authority.0.data}' '${var.project}-${var.stage}'
USERDATA
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "orbix-mvp" {
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.orbix-mvp-node.name}"
  image_id                    = "${data.aws_ami.eks-worker.id}"
  instance_type               = "c5.large"
  name_prefix                 = "${var.project}-${var.stage}"
  security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.orbix-mvp-node.id}"]
  user_data_base64            = "${base64encode(local.orbix-mvp-node-userdata)}"
  key_name                    = "devops"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

So I've added the already generated SSH key under name `devops` to the launch configuration. I can SSH into manually created EC2 instances with that key, however I can't seem to SSH into instances created by this config.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT:

Node Security Group Terraform:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "orbix-mvp-node" {
  name        = "${var.project}-${var.stage}-node"
  description = "Security group for all nodes in the ${var.project}-${var.stage} cluster"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.orbix-mvp.id}"

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = "${
    map(
     "Name", "${var.project}-${var.stage}-node",
     "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.project}-${var.stage}", "owned",
    )
  }"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "demo-node-ingress-self" {
  description              = "Allow node to communicate with each other"
  from_port                = 0
  protocol                 = "-1"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.orbix-mvp-node.id}"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.orbix-mvp-node.id}"
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "ingress"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "demo-node-ingress-cluster" {
  description              = "Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane"
  from_port                = 1025
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.orbix-mvp-node.id}"
  source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.orbix-mvp-cluster.id}"
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "ingress"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "demo-node-port-22" {
  description              = "Add SSH access"
  from_port                = 22
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = "${aws_security_group.orbix-mvp-node.id}"
  cidr_blocks              = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  to_port                  = 22
  type                     = "ingress"
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you attempt to SSH into the instances in the ASG? And are you using the official EKS image and then using the `ec2-user`?

Comment: Ooh it is indeed the official image, however I was using the username `ubuntu` for some reason. You're most likely right and it would work with the `ec2-user`. Now just to figure out why my connection is timing out despite the fact that I've allowed SSH access from all hosts to the instance.

Comment: What security group rules do you have in `aws_security_group.orbix-mvp-node`? This would be easier if you includes all of the relevant code here.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I added the Security Group Terraform resource too.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Btw I was able to connect - it worked with the `ec2-user` username. Can you post this as the answer so I can mark it in case someone stumbles upon this question?